# Terrible voice to text detection with pocketsphinx

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I followed the tutorial [here](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/) for getting pocketsphinx up and running on Android.  I ran the application on a Samsung Galaxy 2 and started speaking.

The problem is that the performance is terrible.  I might say "Hello" and the phone will output "That" on the screen. It is definitely detecting noise through the mic because there is output only when I am speaking.  I think there must be something wrong with my setup.

Does anyone know why I am getting such bad performance?

```
public RecognizerTask() {
    pocketsphinx
    //      .setLogfile("/sdcard/Android/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx/pocketsphinx.log");
        .setLogfile("/mnt/sdcard/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx/pocketsphinx.log");

    Config c = new Config();
    /*
     * In 2.2 and above we can use getExternalFilesDir() or whatever it's
     * called
     */
    /*
    c.setString("-hmm",
            "/sdcard/Android/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k");
    c.setString("-dict",
            "/sdcard/Android/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx/lm/en_US/hub4.5000.dic");
    c.setString("-lm",
            "/sdcard/Android/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx/lm/en_US/hub4.5000.DMP");
    */
    c.setString("-hmm", "/mnt/sdcard/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k");
    c.setString("-dict", "/mnt/sdcard/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx/lm/en_US/hub4.5000.dic");
    c.setString("-lm", "/mnt/sdcard/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx/lm/en_US/hub4.5000.DMP");
    c.setString("-rawlogdir", "/mnt/sdcard/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx"); // Only use it to store the audio

    /*
    c.setString("-hmm",
    "/sdcard/Android/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx/hmm/zh/tdt_sc_8k");
    c.setString("-dict",
    "/sdcard/Android/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx/lm/zh_TW/mandarin_notone.dic");
    c.setString("-lm",
    "/sdcard/Android/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx/lm/zh_TW/gigatdt.5000.DMP");
    */
    //c.setString("-rawlogdir", "/sdcard/Android/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx");
    c.setFloat("-samprate", 8000.0);
    c.setInt("-maxhmmpf", 2000);
    c.setInt("-maxwpf", 10);
    c.setInt("-pl_window", 2);
    c.setBoolean("-backtrace", true);
    c.setBoolean("-bestpath", false);
    this.ps = new Decoder(c);
    this.audio = null;
    this.audioq = new LinkedBlockingQueue<short[]>();
    this.use_partials = false;
    this.mailbox = Event.NONE;
}
```

pocketsphinx.log

```
INFO: cmd_ln.c(691): Parsing command line:


Current configuration:
[NAME]      [DEFLT]     [VALUE]
-agc        none        none
-agcthresh  2.0     2.000000e+00
-alpha      0.97        9.700000e-01
-ascale     20.0        2.000000e+01
-aw     1       1
-backtrace  no      no
-beam       1e-48       1.000000e-48
-bestpath   yes     yes
-bestpathlw 9.5     9.500000e+00
-bghist     no      no
-ceplen     13      13
-cmn        current     current
-cmninit    8.0     8.0
-compallsen no      no
-debug              0
-dict               
-dictcase   no      no
-dither     no      no
-doublebw   no      no
-ds     1       1
-fdict              
-feat       1s_c_d_dd   1s_c_d_dd
-featparams         
-fillprob   1e-8        1.000000e-08
-frate      100     100
-fsg                
-fsgusealtpron  yes     yes
-fsgusefiller   yes     yes
-fwdflat    yes     yes
-fwdflatbeam    1e-64       1.000000e-64
-fwdflatefwid   4       4
-fwdflatlw  8.5     8.500000e+00
-fwdflatsfwin   25      25
-fwdflatwbeam   7e-29       7.000000e-29
-fwdtree    yes     yes
-hmm                
-input_endian   little      little
-jsgf               
-kdmaxbbi   -1      -1
-kdmaxdepth 0       0
-kdtree             
-latsize    5000        5000
-lda                
-ldadim     0       0
-lextreedump    0       0
-lifter     0       0
-lm             
-lmctl              
-lmname     default     default
-logbase    1.0001      1.000100e+00
-logfn              
-logspec    no      no
-lowerf     133.33334   1.333333e+02
-lpbeam     1e-40       1.000000e-40
-lponlybeam 7e-29       7.000000e-29
-lw     6.5     6.500000e+00
-maxhmmpf   -1      -1
-maxnewoov  20      20
-maxwpf     -1      -1
-mdef               
-mean               
-mfclogdir          
-min_endfr  0       0
-mixw               
-mixwfloor  0.0000001   1.000000e-07
-mllr               
-mmap       yes     yes
-ncep       13      13
-nfft       512     512
-nfilt      40      40
-nwpen      1.0     1.000000e+00
-pbeam      1e-48       1.000000e-48
-pip        1.0     1.000000e+00
-pl_beam    1e-10       1.000000e-10
-pl_pbeam   1e-5        1.000000e-05
-pl_window  0       0
-rawlogdir          
-remove_dc  no      no
-round_filters  yes     yes
-samprate   16000       1.600000e+04
-seed       -1      -1
-sendump            
-senlogdir          
-senmgau            
-silprob    0.005       5.000000e-03
-smoothspec no      no
-svspec             
-tmat               
-tmatfloor  0.0001      1.000000e-04
-topn       4       4
-topn_beam  0       0
-toprule            
-transform  legacy      legacy
-unit_area  yes     yes
-upperf     6855.4976   6.855498e+03
-usewdphones    no      no
-uw     1.0     1.000000e+00
-var                
-varfloor   0.0001      1.000000e-04
-varnorm    no      no
-verbose    no      no
-warp_params            
-warp_type  inverse_linear  inverse_linear
-wbeam      7e-29       7.000000e-29
-wip        0.65        6.500000e-01
-wlen       0.025625    2.562500e-02

INFO: cmd_ln.c(691): Parsing command line:
\
    -nfilt 20 \
    -lowerf 1 \
    -upperf 4000 \
    -wlen 0.025 \
    -transform dct \
    -round_filters no \
    -remove_dc yes \
    -svspec 0-12/13-25/26-38 \
    -feat 1s_c_d_dd \
    -agc none \
    -cmn current \
    -cmninit 56,-3,1 \
    -varnorm no 

Current configuration:
[NAME]      [DEFLT]     [VALUE]
-agc        none        none
-agcthresh  2.0     2.000000e+00
-alpha      0.97        9.700000e-01
-ceplen     13      13
-cmn        current     current
-cmninit    8.0     56,-3,1
-dither     no      no
-doublebw   no      no
-feat       1s_c_d_dd   1s_c_d_dd
-frate      100     100
-input_endian   little      little
-lda                
-ldadim     0       0
-lifter     0       0
-logspec    no      no
-lowerf     133.33334   1.000000e+00
-ncep       13      13
-nfft       512     512
-nfilt      40      20
-remove_dc  no      yes
-round_filters  yes     no
-samprate   16000       8.000000e+03
-seed       -1      -1
-smoothspec no      no
-svspec             0-12/13-25/26-38
-transform  legacy      dct
-unit_area  yes     yes
-upperf     6855.4976   4.000000e+03
-varnorm    no      no
-verbose    no      no
-warp_params            
-warp_type  inverse_linear  inverse_linear
-wlen       0.025625    2.500000e-02

INFO: acmod.c(246): Parsed model-specific feature parameters from /mnt/sdcard/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/feat.params
INFO: feat.c(713): Initializing feature stream to type: '1s_c_d_dd', ceplen=13, CMN='current', VARNORM='no', AGC='none'
INFO: cmn.c(142): mean[0]= 12.00, mean[1..12]= 0.0
INFO: acmod.c(167): Using subvector specification 0-12/13-25/26-38
INFO: mdef.c(517): Reading model definition: /mnt/sdcard/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/mdef
INFO: mdef.c(528): Found byte-order mark BMDF, assuming this is a binary mdef file
INFO: bin_mdef.c(336): Reading binary model definition: /mnt/sdcard/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/mdef
INFO: bin_mdef.c(513): 50 CI-phone, 143047 CD-phone, 3 emitstate/phone, 150 CI-sen, 5150 Sen, 27135 Sen-Seq
INFO: tmat.c(205): Reading HMM transition probability matrices: /mnt/sdcard/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/transition_matrices
INFO: acmod.c(121): Attempting to use SCHMM computation module
INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /mnt/sdcard/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/means
INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 1 codebook, 3 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /mnt/sdcard/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/variances
INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 1 codebook, 3 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(354): 0 variance values floored
INFO: s2_semi_mgau.c(903): Loading senones from dump file /mnt/sdcard/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/sendump
INFO: s2_semi_mgau.c(927): BEGIN FILE FORMAT DESCRIPTION
INFO: s2_semi_mgau.c(1022): Using memory-mapped I/O for senones
INFO: s2_semi_mgau.c(1296): Maximum top-N: 4 Top-N beams: 0 0 0
INFO: phone_loop_search.c(105): State beam -230231 Phone exit beam -115115 Insertion penalty 0
INFO: dict.c(317): Allocating 10319 * 20 bytes (201 KiB) for word entries
INFO: dict.c(332): Reading main dictionary: /mnt/sdcard/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx/lm/en_US/hub4.5000.dic
INFO: dict.c(211): Allocated 44 KiB for strings, 69 KiB for phones
INFO: dict.c(335): 6212 words read
INFO: dict.c(341): Reading filler dictionary: /mnt/sdcard/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/noisedict
INFO: dict.c(211): Allocated 0 KiB for strings, 0 KiB for phones
INFO: dict.c(344): 11 words read
INFO: dict2pid.c(396): Building PID tables for dictionary
INFO: dict2pid.c(404): Allocating 50^3 * 2 bytes (244 KiB) for word-initial triphones
INFO: dict2pid.c(131): Allocated 30200 bytes (29 KiB) for word-final triphones
INFO: dict2pid.c(195): Allocated 30200 bytes (29 KiB) for single-phone word triphones
INFO: ngram_model_arpa.c(77): No \data\ mark in LM file
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(142): Will use memory-mapped I/O for LM file
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(196): ngrams 1=5001, 2=436879, 3=418286
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(242):     5001 = LM.unigrams(+trailer) read
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(288):   436879 = LM.bigrams(+trailer) read
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(314):   418286 = LM.trigrams read
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(339):    37293 = LM.prob2 entries read
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(359):    14370 = LM.bo_wt2 entries read
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(379):    36094 = LM.prob3 entries read
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(407):      854 = LM.tseg_base entries read
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(463):     5001 = ascii word strings read
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(99): 457 unique initial diphones
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(147): 0 root, 0 non-root channels, 27 single-phone words
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(186): Creating search tree
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(191): before: 0 root, 0 non-root channels, 27 single-phone words
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(326): after: max nonroot chan increased to 13439
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(338): after: 457 root, 13311 non-root channels, 26 single-phone words
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(156): fwdflat: min_ef_width = 4, max_sf_win = 25
INFO: cmd_ln.c(691): Parsing command line:


Current configuration:
[NAME]      [DEFLT]     [VALUE]
-agc        none        none
-agcthresh  2.0     2.000000e+00
-alpha      0.97        9.700000e-01
-ascale     20.0        2.000000e+01
-aw     1       1
-backtrace  no      no
-beam       1e-48       1.000000e-48
-bestpath   yes     yes
-bestpathlw 9.5     9.500000e+00
-bghist     no      no
-ceplen     13      13
-cmn        current     current
-cmninit    8.0     8.0
-compallsen no      no
-debug              0
-dict               
-dictcase   no      no
-dither     no      no
-doublebw   no      no
-ds     1       1
-fdict              
-feat       1s_c_d_dd   1s_c_d_dd
-featparams         
-fillprob   1e-8        1.000000e-08
-frate      100     100
-fsg                
-fsgusealtpron  yes     yes
-fsgusefiller   yes     yes
-fwdflat    yes     yes
-fwdflatbeam    1e-64       1.000000e-64
-fwdflatefwid   4       4
-fwdflatlw  8.5     8.500000e+00
-fwdflatsfwin   25      25
-fwdflatwbeam   7e-29       7.000000e-29
-fwdtree    yes     yes
-hmm                
-input_endian   little      little
-jsgf               
-kdmaxbbi   -1      -1
-kdmaxdepth 0       0
-kdtree             
-latsize    5000        5000
-lda                
-ldadim     0       0
-lextreedump    0       0
-lifter     0       0
-lm             
-lmctl              
-lmname     default     default
-logbase    1.0001      1.000100e+00
-logfn              
-logspec    no      no
-lowerf     133.33334   1.333333e+02
-lpbeam     1e-40       1.000000e-40
-lponlybeam 7e-29       7.000000e-29
-lw     6.5     6.500000e+00
-maxhmmpf   -1      -1
-maxnewoov  20      20
-maxwpf     -1      -1
-mdef               
-mean               
-mfclogdir          
-min_endfr  0       0
-mixw               
-mixwfloor  0.0000001   1.000000e-07
-mllr               
-mmap       yes     yes
-ncep       13      13
-nfft       512     512
-nfilt      40      40
-nwpen      1.0     1.000000e+00
-pbeam      1e-48       1.000000e-48
-pip        1.0     1.000000e+00
-pl_beam    1e-10       1.000000e-10
-pl_pbeam   1e-5        1.000000e-05
-pl_window  0       0
-rawlogdir          
-remove_dc  no      no
-round_filters  yes     yes
-samprate   16000       1.600000e+04
-seed       -1      -1
-sendump            
-senlogdir          
-senmgau            
-silprob    0.005       5.000000e-03
-smoothspec no      no
-svspec             
-tmat               
-tmatfloor  0.0001      1.000000e-04
-topn       4       4
-topn_beam  0       0
-toprule            
-transform  legacy      legacy
-unit_area  yes     yes
-upperf     6855.4976   6.855498e+03
-usewdphones    no      no
-uw     1.0     1.000000e+00
-var                
-varfloor   0.0001      1.000000e-04
-varnorm    no      no
-verbose    no      no
-warp_params            
-warp_type  inverse_linear  inverse_linear
-wbeam      7e-29       7.000000e-29
-wip        0.65        6.500000e-01
-wlen       0.025625    2.562500e-02

INFO: cmd_ln.c(691): Parsing command line:
\
    -nfilt 20 \
    -lowerf 1 \
    -upperf 4000 \
    -wlen 0.025 \
    -transform dct \
    -round_filters no \
    -remove_dc yes \
    -svspec 0-12/13-25/26-38 \
    -feat 1s_c_d_dd \
    -agc none \
    -cmn current \
    -cmninit 56,-3,1 \
    -varnorm no 

Current configuration:
[NAME]      [DEFLT]     [VALUE]
-agc        none        none
-agcthresh  2.0     2.000000e+00
-alpha      0.97        9.700000e-01
-ceplen     13      13
-cmn        current     current
-cmninit    8.0     56,-3,1
-dither     no      no
-doublebw   no      no
-feat       1s_c_d_dd   1s_c_d_dd
-frate      100     100
-input_endian   little      little
-lda                
-ldadim     0       0
-lifter     0       0
-logspec    no      no
-lowerf     133.33334   1.000000e+00
-ncep       13      13
-nfft       512     512
-nfilt      40      20
-remove_dc  no      yes
-round_filters  yes     no
-samprate   16000       8.000000e+03
-seed       -1      -1
-smoothspec no      no
-svspec             0-12/13-25/26-38
-transform  legacy      dct
-unit_area  yes     yes
-upperf     6855.4976   4.000000e+03
-varnorm    no      no
-verbose    no      no
-warp_params            
-warp_type  inverse_linear  inverse_linear
-wlen       0.025625    2.500000e-02

INFO: acmod.c(246): Parsed model-specific feature parameters from /mnt/sdcard/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/feat.params
INFO: feat.c(713): Initializing feature stream to type: '1s_c_d_dd', ceplen=13, CMN='current', VARNORM='no', AGC='none'
INFO: cmn.c(142): mean[0]= 12.00, mean[1..12]= 0.0
INFO: acmod.c(167): Using subvector specification 0-12/13-25/26-38
INFO: mdef.c(517): Reading model definition: /mnt/sdcard/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/mdef
INFO: mdef.c(528): Found byte-order mark BMDF, assuming this is a binary mdef file
INFO: bin_mdef.c(336): Reading binary model definition: /mnt/sdcard/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/mdef
INFO: bin_mdef.c(513): 50 CI-phone, 143047 CD-phone, 3 emitstate/phone, 150 CI-sen, 5150 Sen, 27135 Sen-Seq
INFO: tmat.c(205): Reading HMM transition probability matrices: /mnt/sdcard/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/transition_matrices
INFO: acmod.c(121): Attempting to use SCHMM computation module
INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /mnt/sdcard/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/means
INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 1 codebook, 3 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /mnt/sdcard/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/variances
INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 1 codebook, 3 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(354): 0 variance values floored
INFO: s2_semi_mgau.c(903): Loading senones from dump file /mnt/sdcard/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/sendump
INFO: s2_semi_mgau.c(927): BEGIN FILE FORMAT DESCRIPTION
INFO: s2_semi_mgau.c(1022): Using memory-mapped I/O for senones
INFO: s2_semi_mgau.c(1296): Maximum top-N: 4 Top-N beams: 0 0 0
INFO: phone_loop_search.c(105): State beam -230231 Phone exit beam -115115 Insertion penalty 0
INFO: dict.c(317): Allocating 10319 * 20 bytes (201 KiB) for word entries
INFO: dict.c(332): Reading main dictionary: /mnt/sdcard/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx/lm/en_US/hub4.5000.dic
INFO: dict.c(211): Allocated 44 KiB for strings, 69 KiB for phones
INFO: dict.c(335): 6212 words read
INFO: dict.c(341): Reading filler dictionary: /mnt/sdcard/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/noisedict
INFO: dict.c(211): Allocated 0 KiB for strings, 0 KiB for phones
INFO: dict.c(344): 11 words read
INFO: dict2pid.c(396): Building PID tables for dictionary
INFO: dict2pid.c(404): Allocating 50^3 * 2 bytes (244 KiB) for word-initial triphones
INFO: dict2pid.c(131): Allocated 30200 bytes (29 KiB) for word-final triphones
INFO: dict2pid.c(195): Allocated 30200 bytes (29 KiB) for single-phone word triphones
INFO: ngram_model_arpa.c(77): No \data\ mark in LM file
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(142): Will use memory-mapped I/O for LM file
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(196): ngrams 1=5001, 2=436879, 3=418286
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(242):     5001 = LM.unigrams(+trailer) read
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(288):   436879 = LM.bigrams(+trailer) read
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(314):   418286 = LM.trigrams read
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(339):    37293 = LM.prob2 entries read
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(359):    14370 = LM.bo_wt2 entries read
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(379):    36094 = LM.prob3 entries read
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(407):      854 = LM.tseg_base entries read
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(463):     5001 = ascii word strings read
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(99): 457 unique initial diphones
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(147): 0 root, 0 non-root channels, 27 single-phone words
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(186): Creating search tree
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(191): before: 0 root, 0 non-root channels, 27 single-phone words
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(326): after: max nonroot chan increased to 13439
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(338): after: 457 root, 13311 non-root channels, 26 single-phone words
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(156): fwdflat: min_ef_width = 4, max_sf_win = 25
```

And a link to the log file and .raw files

[dl.dropbox.com/s/3dkueyz4wgx174z/pocketsphinx.zip?dl=1](http://dl.dropbox.com/s/3dkueyz4wgx174z/pocketsphinx.zip?dl=1)

Comment: i have also same issue i think this lib was collection of some predefine words like if i say hello then output is "the new", if i say one then output is "he formed" , if i say android then output is "they include trust"...haha.

Comment: Augment your sampling rate.

Comment: Uncomment rawlogdir to store the data you are trying to transcribe. Share that data.

Comment: @Nikolay will do, my wife has the phone at the moment though as she is away, will not be able to post the results until this weekend.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev : can u help me plz on same . when im running demo example on my android device i'm saying "android" but application recognized it as "they include trust",when im saying "one" it recognized it "he formed". i stuck because cmusphinx good lib for Speech Recognition but why im getting this result.Thanks

Comment: ρяσѕρєя K, you need to do the same, enable rawlogdir to store the files, then you need to share the files at least. For more details see http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/faq and http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorial

Comment: @Nikolay, I have done what you said, I have updated the question with the pocketsphinx.log.  I am not sure what to do with the .raw file because I can't seem to attach it.

Comment: You can upload files in archive to dropbox and give here a link

Comment: @Nikolay here is the link  https://dl.dropbox.com/s/3dkueyz4wgx174z/pocketsphinx.zip?dl=1 , the first phrase was "Once upon a time" ... can't remember the others.

Comment: @jax, recording vocabulary must match the vocabulary of the langauge model, or you need to build another language model. See http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorial for details. You are saying "android demo" while the word "android" is not in vocabulary. Try to say something simple.

Comment: For example, the result for the second your recording is "and hurt them or" which is close to "android demo", so it did get the acoustic right, the only issue is the language model used.